# Embedded 2-Submanifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

> $\bf 1.7$ **Submersions. Quotient Manifolds** 
>  
>  **Problem $\bf1.7.1\;$** *Let $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ be given by $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-1.$* 
>  $\quad(1)$ *Prove that $C=f ^{-1}(0)$ is an embedded $2$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^3.$*

Can you help for solving this problem ı am triying to understand embedded 2 submanifold please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly any point on $C$ looks like $ (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),z ) $, so you can find suitable open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ and map $ \phi : C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ as $\phi(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),z) = (\theta,z) $ as charts making $C$ a two dimensional submanifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ which is infact a right circular cylinder.

Comment: I found rank(f)=(2x,2y,O) then ı said rank of f is 1 at every point except (0,0,z) then since this does not belong to C,C is closed embedded submanifold. there are lots of theorem for this problem just ı want to apply this theorem in an good way for my question ı dont understand how you did.I did this way but I am not sure. @smiley06